# Session Management in PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have a iphone application and am using Phonegap for developing the app.My application  using external DB for login.How i store user details after login (like session).
Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shihab.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using the [Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) or [File](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File) APIs.

Alternatively, you could consider [Lawnchair](http://blog.westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are wanting to store you could just use [HTML 5 session storage](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/) (e.g. if its just the username).